# Pair of clauses indicating destination

Tags: предлоги, глаголы-движения, subordinate

How do I say "People move to wherever they can earn more money"?

- Люди переезжают **туда, куда** можно зарабатывать больше денег.
- Люди переезжают **куда** можно зарабатывать больше денег.
- Люди переезжают **туда, где** можно зарабатывать больше денег.
- Люди переезжают **куда, где** можно зарабатывать больше денег.

Comment: I think all variants lack this "ever"-ness of English phrase. I would translate this as "переезжают куда **угодно**, где ".  But this depends on context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct one is the 3rd

> Люди переезж**аю**т **туда**, **где** можно зарабатывать больше денег.

Or a bit shorter

> Люди переезж**аю**т **туда**, **где** больше зарабатывают.

*Please also pay attention to the correct spelling of the word `переезжают`*.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's the syntax I was thinking of the most, by the way. As for the conjugation... ouch, there are too many subtleties in Russian!!! I had amended переедут which would be correct however perfective. Then I came up with переезжать as the imperfective counterpart, but got the conjugation pattern wrong. There's always something we don't know yet in Russian!!

Comment: I would say the second is a bit weird. Usually, at the moment of movement people don't earn money yet. Maybe, `Люди переезжают туда, где больше заработают.` will be better?

Comment: @Dmitry No, it's not weirtd. It's absolutely okay.

Comment: @Abakan the second version in the Dmitry's answer is only okay if *зарабатывают* is understood as referring not to people who *переезжают* but to people in general making the subordinate clause an impersonal sentence like the English *where THEY earn more* in which THEY doesn't mean anyone in particular

Comment: And there may occur even shorter (if somewhat ungrammatical) form: "...переезжают, где можно..." ("туда" omitted, may be spoken with a shortish pause instead of it).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion a more accurate and idiomatic rendering would be with the verb in perfective aspect

> Люди переезжают туда, где можно зарабОТАТЬ больше денег

The "ever"-ness present in the English sentence i think can at least to some degree be conveyed with conditional mood

> Люди переезжают туда, где можно *было бы* зарабОТАТЬ больше денег

With the word **угодно** suggested by Ingaz in my opinion it would sound better with the subordinate clause being introduced with conjunction *чтобы*

> Люди переезжают куда угодно, *чтобы* зарабОТАТЬ больше денег

even though this rendering isn't completely equivalent to the English sentence

A combination *pronoun + угодно* as the main clause indicator for a subordinate clause in a complex sentence doesn't seem typical to Russian. Corpus of Russian language lists very few such cases.